# I smell voting fraud, mod bops me on the nose

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I enjoy detecting stuff that looks like voting fraud and flagging it. I do not flag lightly. I think I'm doing a good job if I see the result of my flag gets a user a reputation deduction and a temporary ban. When that happens, I have done my part.

I always do this in good faith. Not to annoy users, not to overwork moderators, but to keep the site clean. My "reward" is a flag that's marked "helpful" and commented on by a mod with "Thanks, we'll look into it".

Just now I encountered a suspicious case: a question asked by an account younger than my most recent coffee, the error in the title in the question, three sentences trying to explain what they were trying to do, no research effort whatsoever, and a link to an image with a screenshot of the code:

> [image: screenshot of a question that made me wonder why it was upvoted]

And that got an upvote within 10 views and 10 minutes, the downvote came later (from me). So I flagged it with the message *"This upvote is extremely suspicious"*. Similar reports by me from the past few weeks that were marked helpful, and actually got users deleted or suspended:

- "This upvote within seconds and 3 views is not right. Voting fraud?"
- "Three upvotes on this is suspicious. Voting fraud?"
- "I don't trust these two upvotes on a question literally asking for a library. Fraud?"

Now what stares me into my face in my flagging history, on the flag on the question shown above?

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I don't like that it's being declined. Mods do see some flagging statistics when handling flags, right? They know I don't flag every comment or question I come by, and that most of my flags indicate actual problems.

This feels like a slap in the face. Is there a moderator policy on how to handle such flags? Or did I do something wrong? I know that one declined flag won't hurt me in any way, but it's just annoying and demotivates me to flag more.

Comment: I *would* bop you on the nose for that comment, though, if you hadn't self-deleted... */bop*.

Comment: I see crap questions get one or two upvotes all the time. It doesn't have to be malicious. People who write crap questions because they never read the rules will also upvote crap questions because they see nothing wrong with them.

Comment: @Ahmed no, but I like to think I've got a nose for it. I never base it on upvote count vs content quality alone.

Comment: This whole question is either strange or I miss something. A mod reviewed the flag and found no evidence for wrongdoing and you think it is about you? Your previous flag history doesn't matter when reviewing the current flag.

Comment: If you don't like downvotes, don't write your meta post in a ninja-facetious way. If I didn't know any better, a Stack Overflow general of 10+ years of battle hardened experience just played the "this feels like a slap in the face" card for a grand total of *one* flag rejection. Excuse me while I clean off the tea that I just spit on my screen.

Comment: @Gimby eh, I don't get many flags rejected, and when I do, I actually did something wrong. So this felt the same, but I believed I didn't. I wanted some clarification, and got that, thanks to Cody. My current writing style perhaps represents my current mood too much, that's something I can work on, thanks. On the other hand, if the tea incident was at least somewhat amusing, I think I got what I wanted.

Comment: I wasn't offended. If nothing else, this might make for a good canonical. I hate to see good tea go to waste, though. I hope it was something gross like Earl Grey.

Comment: The flagging statistics you mention is probably only for a small subset of users that are obsessed about it. If I remember correctly it started with finding the moderator userscript, which can be installed by anyone and work for one's own profile. Moderators have access to this information for all users though. Like anything else, it's just a [number on a screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC9nB.png) :)

Comment: (gnat melancholically looking at own 134 declines) if these were slaps in the face I would probably be dead already

Comment: @gnat rest in peace then.

Comment: @gnat Really? With "51,825 helpful flags" I'm pretty sure your ratio is just fine :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> This feels like a slap in the face.

It's not. It's not meant to be either a slap in the face or a hit on the nose.

Flags are commonly declined when a moderator chooses to take no action. In this case, there was no voting fraud found, so no action was necessary, and thus the flag was declined for one of the standard decline reasons.

It doesn't mean—and shouldn't be taken to mean—that you did anything wrong in raising the flag.

> Mods do see some flagging statistics when handling flags, right?

Nope.

Not without a userscript that adds them in, at least. I tried one of those for about a day, and then decided it just added visual noise. I never looked at that information anyway. The flagging statistics of the flagger aren't interesting or relevant. The flags still have to be handled, and even a usually-lousy flagger will sometimes hit upon something that does need moderator attention.

Your flagging statistics *do* have some impact on the relative sort order of flagged posts, but we don't usually look at all flags, which is the only view where this sort of weighting really matters. And a single declined flag is…(as you said yourself) not a big deal. Your accuracy is still >95%, which is far better than the majority of flaggers out there.

> Is there a moderator policy on how to handle such flags?

Not really. Different moderators kind of do it differently. Some of us mark flags as "helpful" or "declined" based on whether there was any action taken (*i.e.*, whether the flag brought something relevant to a moderator's attention), which is evidently what happened here. Other mods will mark any flag that they perceive to have been raised in good faith as "helpful". Both strategies have their advantages and disadvantages, and which is preferable has been debated since time immemorial. I doubt a final conclusion will be reached. You can't even base it on a user poll, as I personally have been requested by different users to adopt opposite strategies. This is, of course, impossible.

Comment: _"It doesn't mean—and shouldn't be taken to mean—that you did anything wrong in raising the flag"_ - alright, that's on me then. Thanks. - _"Your accuracy is still >95%, which is far better than the majority of flaggers out there"_ - and thanks! The wording of my question and title are of course a little more dramatic than it actually feels, for the reader's pleasure. Hope at least that succeeded.

Comment: Yes, we all <3 drama.